# how to make an array of scaled random digits

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
np.random.random(X) #where x is a positive integer
```

This gives me an array of X numbers on the interval (0 , 1). However, I want the numbers to be on the interval (-1 , 1) and I don't know how to scaled them in numpy. How can I do this very simply only using numpy?

Comment: subtract 0.5 and multiply by 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use `np.random.uniform`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=5)
array([-0.32235009, -0.8347222 , -0.83968268,  0.78546736,  0.399747  ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the random values by 2, then subtract 1. This yields random values in the range -1 to 1.